# How to automatically break long string constants in Python code using Black formatter?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autoformatting, python-black

Python formatting guidelines, the famous [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends no line longer than [79 chars](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length).

I can easily auto-format my code to a max line length with the [Black Formatter](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), but it does not break long strings. The linter will still complain about a long URL in your code and Black won't help.

Is it possible to automatically break long strings with Black formatter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it is possible due to a [new feature](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/1802).

First make sure that you have a very recent Black formatter installed. Now just run black with the option `--experimental-string-processing`.

In VSCode you can configure it in your `settings.json` file:

```
"python.formatting.blackArgs": [
    "--line-length",
    "99",
    "--experimental-string-processing"
],
```

After you edit `settings.json`, restart Black server for the change to take effect: Cmd/Ctrl + Shift + P -> Black Formatter: Restart Server.

BTW, if you want to increase the default line length, it is a good idea to also change to the same value in your linter:

```
"python.linting.flake8Args": [
        "--max-line-length=99",
],
```

Some teams really prefer longer lines, don't let them use this as a reason for not automatically formatting.

BTW, PEP8 support [greater line length](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length):

> Some teams strongly prefer a longer line length. For code maintained exclusively or primarily by a team that can reach agreement on this issue, it is okay to increase the line length limit up to *99 characters*, provided that comments and docstrings are still wrapped at 72 characters.

Comment: In my workspace settings (I have not checked this for project wide settings), the parameter was `black-formatter.args` not `python.formatting.blackArgs`.

Answer (score 5):

With newer versions of black (e.g., 22.1.0) this functionality is now part of the `--preview` flag.

Comment: _update_ update: it's now been demoted to `--unstable` :)
https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage_and_configuration/the_basics.html#unstable

Answer (score 0):

Black Formatter has a pre-release version that you can update. It works almost every time. But keep in mind that some strings for some reason are still ignored